# WebRTC Swift RemoteStream not Rendering

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, rendering

I have created RTCMTLVideoView throught Outlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var otherEndVideoHolderView : RTCMTLVideoView!
```

And collected RTCMediaStream From the RTCPeerConnectionDelegate Delegate

```
    func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didAdd stream: RTCMediaStream) {
    debugPrint("peerConnection did add stream")

    if let video = stream.videoTracks.first{
        self.remoteVideoTrack = video
        self.delegate?.webRTCClient(self, didReceiveRemoteRender: video)
    }
}
```

After Offer -> Answer -> and peer status to **connected**. Only local video is rendering. Remote video is not rendering.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently worked on Webrtc and add remote stream on collectionview cell. You can use my code. If you have any other issue let me know, i will help also.

```
let stream = VideoCallViewController.arrRemoteStreams[indexPath.row]


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RmoteVideoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RmoteVideoCollectionViewCell

    cell.contentView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

    #if arch(arm64)
    // Using metal (arm64 only)
    let remoteRenderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame:  CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
    remoteRenderer.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    #else
    // Using OpenGLES for the rest
    let remoteRenderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame:  CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
    #endif



     //set stream to cell
    stream.videoTracks.first?.add(remoteRenderer)

    //adding stream to cellview
    cell.contentView.addSubview(remoteRenderer)
```

Comment: Hi Vinod Kumar,
Thanks for your answer. But I have done the above step you have mentioned. Can you direct me toward any reason or scenario which causes this issue. As you see in the screen shot given. I have shared candidates and in 'Connected' Status. Yet remote video are not rendering. I have no Idea What I have done wrong.

Comment: I think there is problem in stream. can you share your code @AlbinMrngStar

Comment: I have used firebase to share the candidate, SDP offer and answers. ViewController( https://bitbucket.org/AlbinMrngStar/workspace/snippets/aLj5M8 ),  WebRTCClient(https://bitbucket.org/AlbinMrngStar/workspace/snippets/znp5BR), IceServer ("stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302"). Thanks for your support.

Comment: self.delegate?.webRTCClient(self, didReceiveRemoteRender: video)

Please confirm this delegate called or not

Comment: This delegate is called when the offer is received. 

 if let video = stream.videoTracks.first{
            self.remoteVideoTrack = video
            self.delegate?.webRTCClient(self, didReceiveRemoteRender: video)
        }
and I have used it to render video on RemoteView

   func webRTCClient(_ client: WebRTCClient,
                      didReceiveRemoteRender remoteRenderer : RTCVideoTrack) {
        remoteRenderer.add(self.otherEndVideoHolderView)
        
    }

Comment: this is the string received on candidate : "candidate:1331253593 1 udp 2122194687 169.254.97.106 49272 typ host generation 0 ufrag ykEo network-id 2 network-cost 10", and for some reasons  my SDP_id is "audio". I am not sure, could this be the reason.(https://prnt.sc/t0pd1t)

Comment: I got it your issue , will share some code snippet. give me some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216051/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-and-albinmrngstar).

Comment: I am also facing same issue , not able to render remote stream, my i am able to see my local stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with WEBRTC for iPhone X and 11s. I've filed a bug report [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11727). If the bug report describes your issue make sure to start it so Google can get on it. Thanks!